# How to create one XML file for each record from a database using MarkupBuilder?

Tags: xml, grails, groovy

I'm pretty new to Groovy so here's my first challenge :-)

I need to create XML files from the result of DB query.

I can create one XML file containing all records from a DB Table:

**FILE.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
  <Part>12345</Part>
</items>
<items>
  <Part>67890</Part>
</items>
```

But what I need is to create one file per record rather than one file containing all records:

**FILE1.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
  <Part>12345</Part>
</items>
```

**FILE2.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
  <Part>67890</Part>
</items>
```

Does anyone know if there's a simple way of creating multiple XML files using groovy's MarkupBuilder?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this...

```
class Part {
    String partNumber
}

def parts = // get a List of Part objects

parts.eachWithIndex { Part p, int idx ->
    new File("FILE${idx + 1}.xml").withWriter { writer ->
        def builder = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)
        builder.items {
            part(p.partNumber)
        }
    }
}
```

That will create files like FILE1.xml and FILE2.xml that look something like this:

```
<items>
    <part>12345</part>
</items>
```

I hope that helps.